# SPA calling resource servers protected with two different identity providers

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c, bearer-token

We have a SPA (angular) deployed which authenticates against an azure AD B2C and retrieves tokens that are then used to call some rest APIs.

Now I've been asked to call some other APIs (not under our control) protected by another azure AD B2C (again, not under our control). I don't think that there is any way to "federate" the two AD B2C.

Moreover I don't know if there is a way to obtain access tokens from an AD B2C using some hidden credentials (let's say a technical user/password defined on the second AD B2C) which I wouldn't use in the SPA for obvious reasons but then I could use my authenticated APIs as a proxy to obtain the token from the second B2C and then call the external APIs with the obtained token.

Am I missing something or I've been asked something not feasible with Azure AD B2C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I've found would be having the supplier of the second azure AD B2C declare a new app registration in their B2C and:

- under "Certificates and Secrets" they would add a new Client secret (which they would share with us and that would need to be recreated at least every two years)
- under "API Permissions" they would need to specify which APIs (via scopes) can be accessed with the tokens generated using the client secret above

Then we would invoke our authenticated APIs (protected with the token obtained from our B2C via an interactive oauth flow) and the APIs would act as a proxy by calling their APIs after we obtained the token via the client secret.

All this could be done with different API containers with an API gateway in front of them for a cleaner architecture so that our core APIs are separated from the proxy APIs.

Does anyone know a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your SPA can't easily have a direct security relationship with 2 independent Authorization Servers (or sets of APIs). Sounds like there are some security boundaries here that would be better managed by your back end APIs, which can keep secrets, unlike your SPA.

A useful pattern sometimes is to design 2 levels of API such as this:

- Online Sales SPA is running for a user in Western USA
- The SPA calls an Online Sales (Entry Point) API hosted in Eastern USA, 3000 miles from the end user
- The entry point API aggregates calls to core APIs with low latency, since they are all hosted next to each other
- The entry point API can also deal with security boundaries, such as forwarding calls to the new set of APIs

Personally I like your proxying suggestion, but I would not do it in a Core Microservice - I would instead assign this responsibility to an Entry Point / Aggregate API as above. This results in an extra layer, but only requires simple code, and you avoid adding complexity to any other components.

Comment: Yes another set of API and/or an API Gateway would certainly create a cleaner architecture, but I think it's out of scope for this question... I'll add it as a note to my answer and mark it as The Answer, since no one else is answering I guess there is no better way to accomplish this "multi B2C scenario".